# Expand only one section w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know it's been done before but I'm trying to write this from scratch myself...

I have Q & A section in the following format:

```
<div class="Q">aaaa</div>
<div class="A">bbbb</div>

<div class="Q">cccc</div>
<div class="A">dddd</div>
```

I need to click Q and expand A immediately below. Only one section should be expanded at a time. For example, if I have A:bbbb expanded and then I click Q:cccc I need to collapse A:bbbb and expand A:dddd.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$(".A").hide();
$(".Q").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

How do I collapse any possibly open section before opening the new one without making it collapse first before expanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy as this:

```
$('.q').click(function() {
    $('.a:visible').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).next('.a').is(":hidden").slideDown('slow');
})
```

Comment: This is great, unless you click the header to collapse expanded section... http://jsfiddle.net/a7DyJ/1/

Comment: Good, but make sure you don't open the next a wich is visible, meaning it can be the answer of another question :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $answers = $(".A").hide(); // cache this to avoid overhead
$(".Q").click(function() {
    var $thisA = $(this).next('div.A');
    $answers
        .filter(':visible')
        .not($thisA)
        .slideUp('slow');
    $thisA.slideDown('slow');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/9ENRu/)

Comment: Is there a way to collapse all by clicking the header of the open section?

Comment: @santa: What do you mean collapse all? Collapse everything and not open the current one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
$(".A").hide();
$(".Q").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div:first").slideToggle("slow");
});
```