# Add/remove class on secrtion collapse/expand w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following logic to expand / collapse Q & A sections. I am trying to add a class to "A" to indicate collapsed/expanded state. I think I'm overcomplicating the matter, and it doesn't work...

```
$(".A").hide();
$(".Q").click(function() {
    $(".A:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).next(".A:hidden").slideDown("slow");

   // part below does not work !!!
    $(this).each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
        } else {
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
        }
    });
});

<div class="Q"><span class="collapsed"></span>aaaa</div>
<div class="A">bbbb</div>

<div class="Q"><span class="collapsed"></span>cccc</div>
<div class="A">dddd</div>
```

Comment: Why not edit your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404363/expand-only-one-section-w-jquery) to count for this extra requirement?

Comment: I felt like it was a separate question, although it is  connected to the previous... Not sure if it is a good idea to mix other issues into original question, since it was resolved successfully.

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Je5dU/)?

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Can you post it as an answer so that I could accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".A").hide();
$(".Q").click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $(".A:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $(".Q span.expanded")
        .removeClass('expanded')
        .addClass('collapsed');
    $(this)
        .next(".A:hidden")
        .slideDown("slow", function(){
            $('span.collapsed', that)
                .removeClass('collapsed')
                .addClass('expanded');
        });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Je5dU/)